# Is it possible to modify the input format for dates in front end form?

Tags: datetime, guest-entries

From other threads and my own tests a date field needs to be input in the format of 10/15/2012 (mm/dd/yyyy). But that's not very "British", is there any way to modify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul, when I change the Locale setting to British English (en_gb) **within the database**, the Post Date field's date-format changes to dd/mm/yyyy.

In DB: databaseName > **craft_locales** > Change "en" to "en_gb"

Let us know how you get on :)

Comment: This is weird, I did have my locale set to en_gb already and I just tried the dd/mm/yyyy format in my form and it worked. But previous tests only worked with mm/dd/yyyy format, which I got from a couple of other SE threads. Anyway sorted now thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked @PaulFrost!